# Using a struct is OK, using a class throws OutOfMemoryException (A* algorithm)

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct, a-star

I'm going through a quite troublesome problem and I don't know what happens and why it happens. I'm working on a quite high-intensive pathfinding algorithm (A*) and I'm doing quite a good number of assignments and manipulation over this struct:

```
public struct CellInfo
{
    public int MinCost;
    public CPos Path;
    public bool Seen;

    public CellInfo(int minCost, CPos path, bool seen)
    {
        MinCost = minCost;
        Path = path;
        Seen = seen;
    }
}
```

This struct is mutable because I need to update the values that are within, so I thought it would be a good idea to turn it into a class. However, making the simple change of "struct" to "class" ends up leading, short after application startup, to an OutOfMemoryException and I don't know why. Can someone shed some light about this issue?

This is the most intensive portion of the algorithm just for reference:

```
public CPos Expand(IWorld world)
    {
        var currentMinNode = OpenQueue.Pop();
        while (CellInfo[currentMinNode.Location].Seen)
        {
            if (OpenQueue.Empty)
                return currentMinNode.Location;

            currentMinNode = OpenQueue.Pop();
        }

        var pCell = CellInfo[currentMinNode.Location];
        pCell.Seen = true;
        CellInfo[currentMinNode.Location] = pCell;

        // This current cell is ok; check all immediate directions:
        Considered.Add(currentMinNode.Location);

        var directions = GetNeighbors(currentMinNode.Location, pCell.Path);

        for (var i = 0; i < directions.Length; ++i)
        {
            var direction = directions[i];

            var neighborCPos = currentMinNode.Location + direction;

            // Is this direction flat-out unusable or already seen?
            // TODO: The "as Actor" is made to just isolate this clase, but in the future
            // everything should use IActor implementation instead of concrete class.
            if (!world.IMap.Contains(neighborCPos) ||
                CellInfo[neighborCPos].Seen ||
                !mobileInfo.CanEnterCell(world as World, Self as Actor, neighborCPos, IgnoredActor as Actor, CheckForBlocked ? CellConditions.TransientActors : CellConditions.None) ||
                (customBlock != null && customBlock(neighborCPos)))
                continue;

            var cellCost = CalculateCellCost(world, neighborCPos, direction);
            var gCost = CellInfo[currentMinNode.Location].MinCost + cellCost;

            // Cost is even higher; next direction:
            if (gCost > CellInfo[neighborCPos].MinCost)
                continue;

            // Now we may seriously consider this direction using heuristics:
            var hCost = Heuristic(neighborCPos);

            var neighborCell = CellInfo[neighborCPos];
            neighborCell.Path = currentMinNode.Location;
            neighborCell.MinCost = gCost;
            CellInfo[neighborCPos] = neighborCell;

            OpenQueue.Add(new PathDistance(gCost + hCost, neighborCPos));

            if (gCost > MaxCost)
                MaxCost = gCost;

            Considered.Add(neighborCPos);
        }

        // Sort to prefer the cheaper direction:
        // Array.Sort(nextDirections, (a, b) => a.Second.CompareTo(b.Second));
        return currentMinNode.Location;
    }
```

Comment: Well how many instances of this have you got? (We don't have much context here... we've no idea what `OpenQueue` is, or what `CellInfo[currentMinNode.Location]` is, etc.

Comment: In which line do you get the OutOfMemoryException? Doesn't it say?

Comment: Please, refer to https://github.com/Rydra/OpenRA/blob/upstream/pathfinder/OpenRA.Mods.Common/Traits/World/PathFinder.cs and https://github.com/Rydra/OpenRA/blob/upstream/pathfinder/OpenRA.Mods.Common/Traits/World/PathSearch.cs for full contextual information

Comment: You give no evidence of where the OOM originates other than this is the most intensive, don't answer the question of size, and send us to a link.

Comment: Without [a good, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's not possible to answer. I will tell you that you absolutely should not use a mutable struct; you're just asking for bugs that way. Most likely you have a bug in your A* implementation, possibly an infinite cycle in the graph or something like that; there's no good reason a typical A* scenario should have any trouble with memory constraints. But if we can't run your A* algorithm, it's a lot harder to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: It throws an OutOfMemoryException at the MakeBidiPath function from the NonCachedPathFinder class, when constructing the path built by the Astar (when executes the ret.Add(q)). Can't see the values in the ret array at the time of crash (VS says that the function could not be evaluated due to the memory exception)

Comment: @Peter Duniho the algorithm works fine as long as I keep it as a struct.

Comment: What's the map size?

Comment: "the algorithm works fine as long as I keep it as a struct" -- so you say, and I'm sure you believe. But you are using a mutable struct, which could easily lead to bugs, and you may or may not readily notice those bugs. Nevertheless, the requirement that you provide a good code example is simply factual; if you want a good answer, you need to provide a good code example.

Comment: @Chris 128x128. Peter Duniho precisely, that's why I want to make that struct a class, but if I do this change it throws the exception. It's a quite hard question to express without the full-blown app running :/

Comment: @JonSkeet I've made a run and at the time of crash I got 32600 instances of that class(supposing the GC collected the rest correctly)

Comment: Hmm. That's really not many at all. What does CPos look like? It's somewhat hard to work out what's going on here... are you able to reduce the problem to a short but complete example which is at least *reasonably* representative?

Comment: CPos is just a couple of ints X, Y. I will try to compact the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. When it was a struct, everytime I was passing around variables they were copies instead of references, so every new data structure composed of CellInfo I created was brand new.

When changing to class, instead of copies they were references, and at some points of my code this caused several unwanted side effects that ended up in a infinite loop, which ultimately provoked the out of memory error.

Yeah, after all it was a problem of tracking down the problem, memory profiling, doing experiments and find the reason why a certain variable has a weird value.

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar experience, and I found the following details. Struct instances are created at stack, but class instances are created at heap and garbage collector clears each part of memory with struct faster then with class. Another facet of problem is that class instance has more memory then struct. For example here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231120/Reducing-memory-footprint-and-object-instance-size mentiones that Object has a 12 bytes and  + 4 possibly unused bytes depending on your class (I don't know purpose of padding). As a way of solution, I propose you extensive idea ( http://bhrnjica.net/2012/07/22/with-net-4-5-10-years-memory-limit-of-2-gb-is-over/ ), or maybe you can modify your algorithm and avoid big array of data in memory

Comment: "Struct instances are created at stack" - that's an oversimplification. For example, when you have a struct field within a class, the value will still be on the heap - just within the object. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx